# chrome highlight text search tab

Tags: android, google-chrome

Any suggestions about a library that provide the tab popup opens when highlighting a text on chrome, I haven't found any results on google and also I have seen it before but I don't remember where, If anyone just correct for me the topic I am searching about, or linked to me the library I would be thankful

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this [BottomSheet library](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet) that do a similar view that's might help anyone is searching for the same topic

[image]